# Remove a previously deselected package to install postgres?

Tags: installation, apt, updates, package-management, postgresql

---

So I was meant to run

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
apt-get update
apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

but instead I ran without the previous two commands

```
apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

which I then followed with:

```
apt-get --purge remove postgres
apt-get auto-remove
```

and tried to start back up properly from the first step however, my machine is still installing postgres 8.4 instead of 9.2.

How can I get it to stop doing that?

Edit: I see that the package is not being fetched...

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pitt/postgresql/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
```

May be a server error that just happens to be live the first time I try to install it.

Edit 2: Turns out that it is using "pitt" instead of "pitta" for some reason...will completely restart. ARGHH.

Edit 3: pitti not pitta

Comment: Just commenting, it is *pitti* not *pitt* or *pitta* and the package name is **postgresql-9.2** not just **postgresql**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are searching for is `postgresql-9.2` not `potgresql` according to the ppa you are using.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2 libpq-dev
```

Comment: how can you tell? I was following the railscasts on the subject and they just used postgresql not postgresql-9.2? that would be very handy information...

Comment: He probably just looked at Pitti's launchpad account. https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql